# Solving exactly/approximate this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, power-series

I have the following series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(\frac{a}{k}\right)^k\left(\frac{b}{N-k}\right)^{(N-k)}$$

My question is how do you calculate this sequence exactly? I was thinking that if it is not possible to get an exact numerical solution, what would be a "good" approximation. I tried replacing the powers with factorials but that is not a good approximation I guess and I was unable to calculate the sum after that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(\frac{a}{k}\right)^k\left(\frac{b}{N-k}\right)^{(N-k)}$

Expanding the powers:

$\sum_{k=1}^{N}{a^k\over{k^k}}$$\frac{{b^N}{b^{-k}}}{{{(N-k)}^N{(N-k)}^{-k}}}$=$\sum_{k=1}^{N}{\left(-{a\over{b}}\right)}^k$${\left(b\over{N}\right)}^N$${\left(1-{k\over N}\right)}^{-N}$${\left(1-{N\over k}\right)}^{k}$=

Using the following estimation: ${1+x}\lt{e^x}$

$\lt{\left(b\over{eN}\right)}^N$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}{\left(-{a\over{b}}\right)}^k$${e^k}$, this is sum of a geometric series, where the $q={\left(-{ae\over{b}}\right)}$.